# Averaging a finite representation to get an equivalent representation

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory

Our professor showed us that any representation $\rho$ of a finite group $G$ over a finite dimensional Hilbert space $(V,\left\langle ,\right\rangle')$, is equivalent to a unitary representation.
It was defined as:

> $$\langle v, w\rangle \stackrel{\text { def }}{=} \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G}\langle \rho(g)v, \rho(g) w\rangle'$$

I have two questions:

1. Why do we need $\frac{1}{|G|}$? It seems the proof would work even without it.
2. First question might help with the second one - Is it not always true for an infinite group? Does the proof fail because of the sum? Why so?

Comment: I think you mean a finite-dimensional Hilbert space.

Comment: Yes thank you, I'll edit it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re right that the inner product could be defined without the factor $\frac1{|G|}$; it, would still be an inner product, and the representation would still be unitary with respect to it. In that sense we don’t “need” the factor. This sort of operation is often regarded as “averaging over the group” (see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_representation): “Many of the results of finite group representation theory are proved by averaging over the group.”). If you drop that factor, you’d be summing over the group instead; in this case, that wouldn’t make a difference.
You can see two such averaging operations that *can’t* be replaced by sums here: [Projection operator in group representation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2997696).

As to the second question, you’re right that the problem is with the sum, which wouldn’t be defined in an infinite group. However, for a [compact group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_group) the sum could be replaced by an integral.